# How to load GDI::Image (GIF) from Resource in c++(winapi)?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, animated-gif

I'm making a window c++ with winapi(non-MFC) and showing gif. For this Im using GDI++. I'm loading a gif to GDI::Image from the path, but I want to load it from resources. How can I do it?

```cpp
    hMWDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    pGphcs = new Graphics(hMWDC);
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
    PathRemoveFileSpecW(path);
    PathAppendW(path, L"gifs\\test.gif");
    pImg = new Image(path);

    if (pImg) {
        nFrmCnt = pImg->GetFrameCount(&FrameDimensionTime);
        SetTimer(hWnd, DRAW_ANIM, 100, NULL);

    }
case WM_TIMER:
        if (wParam == DRAW_ANIM)
        {
            pImg->SelectActiveFrame(&FrameDimensionTime, nFrm);
            Rect DRC(0, 0, pImg->GetWidth(), pImg->GetHeight());
            pGphcs->Clear(Color(128, 128, 128));


            pGphcs->DrawImage(pImg, DRC);
            if (nFrm < (nFrmCnt - 1)) nFrm++; else nFrm = 0;
        }

        break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Image [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-image-image(gpimage_status)) that accepts an IStream*.

You can create a stream by calling [SHCreateMemStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) on the raw buffer of a resource, which can be obtained by calling [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea)/[LoadResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource)/[LockResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource) and [SizeOfResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-sizeofresource).

Comment: @TheGamerCoder read the documentation Michael linked to, examples are given.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau   Emm... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-image-image(gpimage_status) from here:

Comment: hr = pIStorage->OpenStream(
      L"StreamImage1", 
      NULL, 
      STGM_READ|STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
      0,
      &pIStream1);

Comment: and No more examples.   OK.  BUT how can  I Use it if there nothing about Resource

Comment: @TheGamerCoder the `Image` constructor doc shows passing an `IStream` obtained from an `IStorage`. `SHCreateMemStream()` takes a memory pointer and size as input and returns an `IStream`. The Resource docs show you how to get a pointer and size for a resource. Not that hard to figure out how to apply one example to another. I posted an answer showing the code.

Comment: I'm beginner in it, so I cant figure. So that's why Im created a question for some code.

Comment: And one moment. Can you say how to insert gif to Resource? Please – 
I dont know how todo it

Comment: @TheGamerCoder Really, how hard could it be to enter "add gif resource" in the search box?

Comment: NO. How to add gif file to RESOURCE file (*.rc).There isn't  any resource type in available. If I want to import gif creating rcdata. OK. And when I open the program.

Comment: hRes = NULL OR FAILED

Comment: Now if you understand

Answer (score 1):

Add the GIF file to your app's resources at compile time. For instance, by compiling an `.rc` file similar to below into a `.res` file that you can then link into your executable (some compilers/IDEs have tools to automate this step):

Resources.rh

```
#define MY_GIF_ID 100
```

Resources.rc

```
#include "Resources.rh"
MY_GIF_ID RCDATA "gifs\\test.gif"
```

Then, you can obtain a pointer to the raw bytes of the resource at runtime.

```c
#include "Resources.rh"

HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_GIF_ID), RT_RCDATA);
if (!hRes) { ... error handling ... } 

HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hMod, hRes);
if (!hGlobal) { ... error handling ... } 

void *pResData = LockResource(hGlobal);
if (!pResData) { ... error handling ... } 

DWORD dwResData = SizeofResource(hMod, hRes);
```

See MSDN for more details:

[Introduction to Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/introduction-to-resources)

[Finding and Loading Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/finding-and-loading-resources)

And then finally, pass the resource bytes to the `Image` constructor that takes an `IStream*` as input:

```c
#include <shlwapi.h>

IStream *pStream = SHCreateMemStream((BYTE*)pResData, dwResData);
if (!pStream) { ... error handling ... } 

pImg = new Image(pStream);
pStream->Release();
```

Comment: Problem is the gif is flick. I tried to return 0 on WM_ERASEBKGND And setting NULL the brush of WNDCLASSEX; It din't help

Comment: @TheGamerCoder that is a completely different issue than loading the GIF from a resource. Post a new question about the flickering. If you are able to successfully load the GIF from a resource then mark an answer as accepted and move on

Comment: OK. I will did it.